# Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.loc\auth.php on line 13

Tags: php, mysql, sql, массивы, count

Помогите понять что я сделал не так? Мучаюсь уже 3 часа. Пересмотрел кучу ответов, ничего пока не подходит.

````
$result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Login` = '$login' AND `Pasword` = '$pass'");
$users = $result->fetch_assoc();
if(count($users)== 0) {
  echo "Такой пользователь не найден";
  exit();
};

print_r($users);
exit();```
````

Comment: И ни в одном не сказано `var_dump($users)`? Или `print_r($users)` что выводит?

Comment: И ни в одном не сказано var_dump($users)? - НЕТ

Comment: print_r($users) что выводит? выводит ровно ничего, ни ошибок, ни данных, НИЧЕГО

Comment: Ну тогда открывай https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-assoc-returnvalues и проникайся

Comment: проблема в том что я делаю все по примеру, который уже создан и работает, делаю все точ в точ, там работает у меня нет.... просто космос...((((

Comment: Если пример работает, а у тебя не работает - значит ты делаешь __не__ точь-в-точь.

Comment: Да версия php банально различается. А именно: до 7.2 и после 7.2: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php#migration72.incompatible.warn-on-non-countable-types Делать count на результат fetch_assoc есть глупость сама по себе.

Comment: Каждого программиста, которые подставляет внешние данные напрямую в запрос, нужно бить по рукам. Читайте внимательно https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php. Я вам советую перейти на более интересную библиотеку для работы с бд - PDO

Comment: @Skydiver19, ну ошибка вам прям и шепчет, что в `$user` падает значение, которое не может быть использовано в функции `count`, в вашем случае скорее всего это bool (false), в случае, когда не был найден ни один юзер. 

Уберите `count`, и оставьте только `if ($user)`, все будет работать корректно.